# Property subract minutes from time with JS/ or Qt

Tags: qt, qml

In a little pickle,

My app is a bedside clock which for a function I need to work out 15 Minutes before the alarm is set to go off but everything I try seems to mess up.

Everything will subract the Minutes fine but it won't roll the time over to the previous hour, for example:

Let's say the alarm time is set for 00:15 now if I subtract 30 Minutes it returns 00:45 where it needs to roll over to the previous hour and return 23:45

The App is based on Qt with a Qt Quick UI so JS will work in a function or it can be done from the Qt/c++ side.

Setting the alarm time doesn't include any kind of date information since it's designed to be a single use bedside clock and not a full on multiple alarm function.

If anyone has any ideas it would be appreciated.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are manually working with hours and minutes. It is much easier to just use the QTime and QDateTime objects of the library and let those do the work for you. For instance if you have your alarm time in a QTime

```
QTime alarmtime = ?;
QTime before = alarmtime.addSecs(-15 * 60);
```

Comment: How did I not think of that :o
Thank you :)